# unable to get facebook app token and secret

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I purchased one site from flippa and that user transferred facebook page also to me and now i am admin of that facebook page but when i enter developer page to get the facebook token and secret i get this error on this page

https://developers.facebook.com/apps/

```
You currently have no apps integrated with Facebook.
```

my facebook page is

https://www.facebook.com/viralfoto/

and i am admin of this page.so i should be able to get the developer access of that page so that i can install facebook wordpress plugin which require token and secret of facebook page. any help will be great

Comment: An app and page are two completely different things. Pages are not apps. Pages therefor have no app token or secret

Comment: @WizKid plz see this link. its facebook page and it is asking for app token and secret http://imgur.com/L23uOpo   so if its not app i have to create one app  with the facebook page ????

Comment: If someone is asking for app id and secret you need to ask them.

Comment: @WizKid u solved my problem. u can give first comment as answer i will accept